# Can't get objectname out of objectobservable

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire, observable

I got a issue i wane try to get some data from the db. I receive the data but I cant display it cause it are object instead of strings. How can I get these object into strings I have tried quiet some things but nothing seems to be working.

***Component.ts***

```
 this.artistitems = af.database.object('/users/'+this.artistid, {preserveSnapshot: true});
    this.artistitems.subscribe(snapshot => {
      this.artistvalues = snapshot.val();
      this.artistitemsid = this.artistvalues.releases;
      console.log(this.artistitemsid)
    });
```

***Output in console from artistitemsid***

```
aroundthefur:Object
b-sides&rarities:Object
diamondeyes(deluxe):Object
gore:Object
koinoyokan:Object
saturdaynightwrist(explicitversion):Object
thestudioalbumcollection:Object
```

***Database***

[image: database]

Everything i try to put in my component.html crashes i have really no idee how i can get the values out of the object instead of getting the object itself

***When i have this in my component.html***

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of artistitemsid">
      {{ item.value }}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

***I recieve this error***

> inline template:8:12 caused by: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: Is the object inside an array of objects ?  is so you need to to iterate the with a *NgFor  also post your html component

Comment: I did post it with the error when i delete the .value in the html i recieve the same error

Comment: Try this and tell me what you get  <li *ngFor="let item of artistitemsid">
      {{ item | json}}
    </li>

Comment: Same error already tried that

Comment: Check my answer for pushing object values to an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken you want to display a list of keys from the artist releases: aroundthefur, b-sides&rarities, etc.

So you can extract those keys from your `releases` object:

```
this.artistitems = af.database.object('/users/'+this.artistid, {preserveSnapshot: true});
this.artistitems.subscribe(snapshot => {
  this.artistvalues = snapshot.val();
  this.artistitemsid = Object.keys(this.artistvalues.releases);
});
```

And iterate with `ngFor` over the resulting array:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of artistitemsid">
    {{ item}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

From your firebase structure artistitemsid  you get back an obeject {}, you cannot use ngFor on an object.

But you should be able to access the values directly with interpolation:

```
{{artistitemsid.gore.value}}
```

Now depending of the value if it is an array of objects then you can iterate it with ngFor

Or you can take the values you get and add them in an array:

You get from firebase something like

```
{aroundthefur:{},b-sides&rarities:{},...}
```

.

```
 this.artistitems.subscribe(snapshot => {
      this.artistvalues = snapshot.val();
      this.artistitemsid = this.artistvalues.releases;

      const myArray = [];
        for (let key in this.artistitemsid){
          myArray.push(this.artistitemsid[key]);
        }
        this.items = myArray;  // items  is declared outside so you can use it on a ngFor

      console.log(myArray)
    });
```

Use the function inside on a ngOnInit, and you will get something like:

```
items = [aroundthefur:{},b-sides&rarities:{},...]
```

And can be used as

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of items">
      {{ item.value }}  // basically is aroundthefur.value
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: 0:Object
1:Object
2:Object
3:Object
4:Object
5:Object
6:Object

This is my output in the console.log(myArray) now xD

Comment: I do get 10 bullets in my webapp though. So it sees that there are 10 in it just still no value

Comment: ["Image"](https://i.gyazo.com/4dd67374174c2d2c85db470f4d691b30.png)

Her is a image of how i see the consolelog